# How to execute direct SQL code on a different database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm writing a Rails application which will monitor data quality over some specific databases. In order to do that, I need to be able to execute direct SQL queries over these databases - which of course are not the same as the one used to drive the Rails application models. In short, this means I can't use the trick of going through the ActiveRecord base connection.

The databases I need to connect to are not known at design time (i.e.: I can't put their details in database.yaml). Rather, I have a model 'database_details' which the user will use to enter the details of the databases over which the application will execute queries at runtime.

So the connection to these databases really is dynamic and the details are resolved at runtime only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a situation like this where I had to connect to hundreds of different instances of an external application, and I did code similar to the following:

```
  def get_custom_connection(identifier, host, port, dbname, dbuser, password)
      eval("Custom_#{identifier} = Class::new(ActiveRecord::Base)")
      eval("Custom_#{identifier}.establish_connection(:adapter=>'mysql', :host=>'#{host}', :port=>#{port}, :database=>'#{dbname}', " +
      ":username=>'#{dbuser}', :password=>'#{password}')")  
    return eval("Custom_#{identifier}.connection")
  end
```

This has the added benefit of not changing your ActiveRecord::Base connection that your models inherit from, so you can run SQL against this connection and discard the object when you're done with it.

Comment: Indeed, the approach is better suited to the problem I had at the time. Thanks a lot for sharing!

Answer (score 11):

You can programmatically establish a connection using a call like this

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
   :adapter  => "mysql",
   :host     => "localhost",
   :username => "myuser",
   :password => "mypass",
   :database => "somedatabase"
)
```

As you see you can replace the somedatabase by a `database_model.database_name` value. The same is true with the adapter and all.

See [`ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001397) for more information.

Then you can use:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.find_by_sql("select * ")
```

to execute your SQL query.

See [`ActiveRecord::Base.find_by_sql` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001302) for more information.

[Mr Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12037/mr-matt) was right if incomplete.

More information, which is outdated but still useful for the design approach, can be found [here](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowtoUseMultipleDatabases) and remember to reconnect to the normal database when you are done.

Comment: The last link is dead. When linking to an offsite resource, it's important to summarize the information in the answer to avoid situations like this. See "[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/153968)"

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this through [`self.establish_connection`](http://blog.whitet.net/articles/2008/01/30/rails-has_many-with-models-over-different-databases).

Comment: Hello Mat,
Actually, that won't do because you have to 'hardcode' the remote database in database.yaml and mines are dynamic, which means I have to connect to them by resolving their connection details at runtime from the model itself.
I'll update my question to make this clearer!
Thanks